# How to close a dropdown list on click outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have modified my html and css. Can anyone suggest on how to hide the checkbox -list dropdown when clicked outside of the dropdown and not inside. Only on "OK" click it should hide inside.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/

```css
.down-arrow-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 0 3px
}

.down-arrow {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiDSf.png");
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 0 0
}

.checkbox-list {
  width: 138px;
  max-height: 210px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(226, 226, 226);
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 0
}

.checkbox-list > li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.8);
  font-weight: 400
}



.checkbox-list > li label {
  color: rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.8);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px
}


.checkbox-list .btn {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  font-size: 13px
}
```

Find below the dropdown arrow image.

[image: dropdown arrow image]

Below script is not working properly

```js
$('body').mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $('#dropdowngroup');
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length == 0) {
    container.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="detailReport">

  <div class="box-table">
    <table class="table detailreport text-center" id="DetailReportGrid" width="100%" style="position:relative;  height:50px;">
      <thead style="position:relative;">
        <tr style="position:relative;">
          <th align="center" width="8%" style="position:relative;">Date</th>
          <th align="center" width="8%" style="position:relative;">Time</th>


          <th align="center" width="13%" style="position:relative;" index=5 name="groupName">
            Group Name
            <div class="down-arrow-wrapper" id="dropdowngroup">
              <a href="#" class="down-arrow"></a>
              <ul class="checkbox-list" id="ul_Groups"></ul>
            </div>
          </th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The drop down is not a button(to clarify). The "Group Name" has a down arrow where the arrow is the only href.

Comment: There is no `dropdown`  in your code and no arrow.

Comment: edited with arrow image

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it like this?

I've changed the `JS` to listen every click event on the `body` and react if the clicked target is `a` and the parent is `#dropdowngroup`. If yes, it will show the `#ul_Groups` and if the click is on the `#ul_Groups` it does the same.

```js
$("body").click(function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName == "A" && $(event.target).parent().attr('id') == "dropdowngroup" || $(event.target).parent().attr('id') == "ul_Groups") {
    $('#ul_Groups').show();
  } else {
    $('#ul_Groups').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#ul_Groups {
  display: none;
}

.down-arrow-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 0 3px
}

.down-arrow {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiDSf.png");
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 0 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="detailReport">

  <div class="box-table">
    <table class="table detailreport text-center" id="DetailReportGrid" width="100%" style="position:relative;  height:50px;">
      <thead style="position:relative;">
        <tr style="position:relative;">
          <th align="center" width="8%" style="position:relative;">Date</th>
          <th align="center" width="8%" style="position:relative;">Time</th>


          <th align="center" width="13%" style="position:relative;" index=5 name="groupName">
            Group Name
            <div class="down-arrow-wrapper" id="dropdowngroup">
              <a href="#" class="down-arrow"></a>
              <ul class="checkbox-list" id="ul_Groups">
                <li>hello</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked good, but I only want the click to be applied on the arrow image.